# Geany plugin to easily rename a file

Tags: filenames, geany

[Geany](http://geany.org/) is a text editor with tabs:　[image: Geany tabs]

Is there a plugin or trick that would enable me to rename files?

For instance I would like to easily rename `editor.c` to `viewer.c`

- Without having to close/reopen the file
- Without having to switch away from the Geany window

No obvious match among at http://plugins.geany.org

Bonus if I can also move files to a different directory, but just name would be already great.
"Save as" is not a good option as it does not delete the previous file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for a plugin.

In the <kbd>Save as …</kbd> window, there are three buttons: "Rename", "Cancel" and "Save".

Try using the <kbd>Rename</kbd> button instead of "Save".

Comment: could be nice if Geany developers rename "save as ..." to "save as/rename"

Comment: If there is a change on the code base, I propose removing the Rename button and doing an Rename implicitly on save when the name is changing (following the notepad++ behavior)

Answer (score 1):

In the tree browser plugin (Menu `Tools` -> `Plugin Manager`) you can do a rename on the file by selecting it and right-click (context menu -> `Rename`).

Don't forget to enable sidebar: Menu `View` -> `Show Sidebar`